# Swift How to convert jsonString to Dictionary and Array[Dictionary]

Tags: json, swift, dictionary

How to convert jsonString to Dictionary ?

```
"{\n \"sender\" : \"system1@example.com\",\n \"data\" : {\n \"text\" : \"Test Message\"\n },\n \"recipients\" : \"system2@example.com\"\n}"
```

How to convert to Array of Dictionary ?

```
"[{\n \"sender\" : \"system1@example.com\",\n \"data\" : {\n \"text\" : \"Test Message\"\n },\n \"recipients\" : \"system2@example.com\"\n},{\n \"sender2\" : \"system2@example.com\",\n \"data\" : {\n \"text\" : \"Test Message2\"\n },\n \"recipients\" : \"system3@example.com\"\n}]"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use convertToDictionary() and convertToArrayOfDictionary()

```
extension String {


    func convertToArrayOfDictionary() -> [[String: Any]]? {
        if let data = data(using: .utf8) {
            return try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [[String: Any]]
        }
        return nil
    }

    func convertToDictionary() -> [String: Any]? {
        if let data = data(using: .utf8) {
            return try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any]
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```